# Java: How to define equals and hashCode when inheriting from superclass?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

If a class from a library doesn't implement `equals` or `hashCode`, how do I correctly implement them  in a subclass or wrapper class so I can do comparisons correctly? Is there a shortcut on IntelliJ that can do this? I guess I am looking for equality based on public `getters` methods

Comment: Unfortunately, Intellij assumes super class has sensible implementations for these methods.  I don't think it can be done without coding it yourself.

Comment: Not familiar with Intellij but could it be a configuration option?